# Падеж имен существительных и неопределенных количественных числительных следующих за словом "достаточно"

Tags: грамотная-речь, падежи

Отрывок из  книжного  текста:

*Глазам достаточно несколько цветов и движения.*

Почему не написано "Глазам достаточно нескольких цветов и движений"? Объясните, пожалуйста, чем можно оправдать форму приведенного  книжного  текста?

Comment: Опечатка, запятые, пробелы — где лишние, где отсутствуют. Большое спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

*Your eyes are pretty happy with some color and movement, you know. **Глазам достаточно несколько цветов и движения**.*

Это всего лишь перевод текста.

Слово ***достаточно*** может быть наречием, предикативом (предикативным наречием) и кратким прилагательным.

Предикатив управляет Р.п., поэтому правильно будет так: ***Глазам достаточно (чего?) нескольких цветов и движения.***

Но возможна такая запись: *Глазам достаточно несколько цветов*. Предикативная основа: *несколько цветов достаточно.* *Достаточно* — краткое прилагательное в роли сказуемого

Краткое прилагательное используется значительно реже, чем  предикатив (чаще в старых текстах), но вряд ли эту форму можно считать запрещенной, например: Эта сумма денег **достаточна** для поездки.

Примеры:

**Достаточно несколько** крупных учёных, чтобы определить расцвет. [Даниил Гранин. Зубр (1987)]

Динамичный! (достаточно **несколько сцен**). [ Письмо отца к дочери (2004)]

Для хорошей работы алгоритма **достаточно несколько** десятков последовательных итераций.  [«Геоинформатика», 2003.06.18.]

Между тем **достаточно несколько** сеансов внушения, чтобы эту привычку искоренить навсегда. [В. М. Бехтерев. (1911)]